# Cannot use Scala class in Java

Tags: java, scala, maven, scala-java-interop

I believe Scala and Java can use classes from each other.

However, I found myself in a situation that my Java class cannot use a Scala class in the same package.

The scala class is defined as:

```
class CustomerService extends AbstractCustomerService {
```

The code trying to use this bit of code is:

```
public Deployer() {
        singletons.add(new CustomerService());
}
```

The error I got is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile (default-compile) on project orderservice: Compilation failure
[ERROR] \devel\raven\services\orderservice\service\src\main\scala\com\mxyy\orderservice\customer\Deployer.java:[12,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class CustomerService
[ERROR] location: class com.mxyy.orderservice.customer.Deployer
```

Can someone give me some hint about this?

Many thanks

Comment: Are your other Scala classes visible in Java? This sounds more like a Maven issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean visibie? How to configure Maven to make it visible?

Comment: The exact solution is here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046422/compilation-error-using-scala-classes-in-java-maven-project][1]

answered by: Thomas Eilermann


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046422/compilation-error-using-scala-classes-in-java-maven-project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

configure your `pom.xml` according to this article:
[joint compliation of scala and java sources](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/joint-compilation-of-scala-and-java-sources)

Comment: this should be in the maven Scala archetype